# Nginx error on Rhel7 nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)

Tags: nginx, rhel7

I know that this question has already been asked, but even after trying all the methods: disabling ipv6, killing the process using port 80 (fuser -k 80/tcp), disabling apache. Removing contents of sites-available directory. The error still persists.

my nginx conf file in /etc/nginx:

```
user  nginx;
worker_processes  2;

error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log warn;
pid        /var/run/nginx.pid;


events {
worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
default_type  application/octet-stream;

log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

sendfile        on;
#tcp_nopush     on;

keepalive_timeout  65;

gzip  on;
include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
}
```

my default.conf in /etc/nginx/conf.d

```
server {
listen       81;
server_name  localhost;

#charset koi8-r;
#access_log  /var/log/nginx/host.access.log  main;

location / {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
    index  index.html index.htm;
}

#error_page  404              /404.html;

# redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
#
error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
location = /50x.html {
    root   /usr/share/nginx/html;
}

# proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
#
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
#}

# pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
# 
#location ~ \.php$ {
#    root           html;
#    fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
#    fastcgi_index  index.php;
#    fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
#    include        fastcgi_params;
#}

# deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
# concurs with nginx's one
#
#location ~ /\.ht {
#    deny  all;
#}
}
```

I am very new to nginx, also could i just make nginx listen to some other port to make this work after listing it in firewall and selinux?

Comment: What does `netstat -ant | grep :80 | grep LISTEN` say?

Comment: THIS> tcp6      0      0 :::80             :::*        LISTEN

Comment: 1925/http this shouldn't happen tho

Answer (score 1):

you have another process bound to port 80.
find it with `netstat -ltnp | grep -w ':80'` and kill it.
after a few seconds you should be running nginx

Comment: It says: tcp6            0            0   :::80          :::*          LISTEN

Answer (score 0):

in php-fpm on supervisor file
add flash --nodaemonize